# Two SSL domains on one Apache2 server; one is served correctly, the other serves the 'Index of /' page

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I have two SSL-secured domains on my Apache2 server running on Ubuntu. `site2.com` is served correctly, but `site1.me` is serving the `Index of /` page, where `/` is apparently the parent directory of both sites. In the `Index of /` page, I see the directories of both of the sites (`site1-me` and `site2-com`), and clicking into them serves the pages as I expect, but at the URL `site1.me/site1-me` or `site1.me/site2-com`.

The relevant part of my config file (or, at least, what I *think* is relevant) is below, with domain names removed (left TLD):

```
# Host multiple domains

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site1.me
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site1-me"
        ServerAlias *.site1.me

        ServerAdmin admin@site1.me

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site1.me
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/site1-me/site1-me-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/site1-me/site1-me-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site2.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site2-com"
        ServerAlias *.site2.com

        ServerAdmin admin@site1.me

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site2.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/site2-com/site2-com-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/site2-com/site2-com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Rewrite*` lines were added by `certbot` automatically.

What I've tried so far:

- Reissuing SSL certificates for both sites
- Restarting the server
- Checking owner/permissions for both site directories. They are identical.
- Reversing the order of the `<VirtualHost>` areas
- Removing `Rewrite*` lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config file was correctly configured in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, however I had the `DocumentRoot` specified as `/var/www/html` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf`. Changing the appropriate line to `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1-me` fixed the issue. `site2` is nowhere to be found in the `sites-available` directory.

The bigger lesson to be learned here is that my config files are currently a mess, and probably only working with generous error handling.